# How to select all TRs inside a table which don't contain an inner element with a class

Tags: jquery

I have a table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><i class="green"></i>2</td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

I have three rows, and inside one of the rows there is an `<i>` element with a class "green". I want to select all the TRs that do not contain the 'green' class and change their color.

With the following in **jQuery** I can select all the TRs which contain the green class and change the background color of their parent TR but I want to do the inverse, select all the TRs that do not contain the green class element and change their background:

```
$('.green').parent().parent().css("background","#000");
```

Comment: try `$('tr').not(':has(.green)');`

Comment: Thanks. This worked!